# Translating .deb package information

Tags: programming, packaging, internationalization

How can I translate the contents of `debian/control` in debian packages so that the Information will be localised when the package is shown in the Software-Centre?

- [image]  for packages in Ubuntu
- for single .deb packages
- for packages in PPAs

Comment: If I may add something related... it'd be nice to know how to do the same for `.desktop` files.

Comment: `.desktop` files contain the translations directly in the file. See Exaile's as an example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/540133/ There are some build system tricks that can be used to merge the info in from `.po` files. `python-distutils-extras` provides helpers for python. Take a look at some of the GNOME packages for autotools examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meta-information for the applications shown in Software-Center is provided by the `app-install-data` package. The title and short description can be translated through [app-install-data's Rosetta page on Launchpad](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/app-install-data-ubuntu/+pots/app-install-data). I'm not sure if it is possible to submit a translation for the packages's long description.

Comment: Does that mean that package information in my PPA, or in a single package that I offer for download somewhere, can't be translated for Ubuntu?

Comment: Hmm... That's a good question. I suppose you could provide an app-install-data-myppa package with the needed info. Canonical provides an app-install-data-partner package in their "partner" repository. Obviously that doesn't seem ideal. Hopefully someone else might have a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another possible solution:

With [Nightmonkey](http://nightmonkey.ubuntu.hu/) you can easily find every piece of the package description. Yes, this page links to the Launchpad translations page.

There aren't frequent updates on the official repositories, so be patient.

Comment: we just updated the descriptions and synced everything a week ago